# Java socket read blocking infinitely

Tags: java, sockets, robots.txt

I have a really strange issue while working with Java sockets. This problem is only happening for a VERY small subset of the urls that I am processing. Let's call an example url abc.com.

Edit: url is `lists.wikimedia.org/robots.txt` that gives me problems.

I can curl/netcat/telnet `lists.wikimedia.org` with path `/robots.txt` perfectly fine. Telnet even tells me the IP address for `lists.wikimedia.org` (see below). However, when I try to do the same using Java socket like the following:

```
Socket s = new Socket("208.80.154.4", 80);  // IP is same as the IP printed by telnet
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(s.getOutputStream());
writer.println("HEAD /robots.txt HTTP/1.1");
writer.println("Host: lists.wikimedia.org");
writer.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
writer.flush();

InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    ...
}
```

The readLine blocks infinitely until the socket times out...

Does anyone have ANY idea why this might be happening? The same code works fine with most of the other URLs, and interestingly enough this bug only happens for some of the ROBOTS.TXT requests... I'm so confused why this might be happening.

Edit:

Interestingly enough, using apache HttpClient library gives me the correct result for `lists.wikimedia.org/robots.txt`. Is there something else I need to do if I want to manually do it via Socket?

Comment: `Socket` doesn't have a `readLine()` method.

Comment: You can't just open the socket and expect them to give you something.. You're gonna have to show some more code if you want better help sooner.

Comment: As in, send a correctly formatted HTTP request.

Comment: Oops, sorry you guys are right, I wasn't paying attention. I added the lines where I get the reader

Comment: Give us the particular URL

Comment: Added actual url that was giving me problems

Comment: @Aubin I used `telnet lists.wikimedia.org 80`, so shouldn't that use port 80?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are missing the additional CRLF to end the HTTP request header. I also would write them explicitly, to avoid platform confusions, like so (untested):

```
writer.print("HEAD /robots.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n");
writer.print("Host: lists.wikimedia.org\r\n");
writer.print("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");
writer.print("\r\n");
writer.flush();
```

also consider using a HTTPURLConnection instead of plain sockets, takes away all this burdons:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
...
```

Comment: I need to use Socket because this is an assignment haha

Comment: One of the typical Java "write once, run everwhere" pitfalls. (Pitfalls used here to avoid the word "lies"). On the other hand, it might be useful to have the correct newline behaviour on each platform, without caring about.

Comment: The problem with using println() isn't that it doesn't work. It is that it uses the system's default line terminator, but the HTTP line terminator isn't system-dependent: it is specified as \r\n (inherited from Telnet actually). So you shouldn't use it *for Telnet-derived protocols.* You shouldn't really use PrintStream or PrintWriter at all over a network, as they swallow exceptions that you need to know about.